# ArgumentOutOfRangeExeption in unity C#

Tags: unity, c#

I keep getting this error:

```
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException (System.ExceptionArgument argument, 
System.ExceptionResource resource) (at <23c160f925be47d7a4fd083a3a62c920>:0)
System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException () (at <23c160f925be47d7a4fd083a3a62c920>:0)
Controller.UpdateDisplays () (at Assets/Scripts/Controller.cs:100)
Controller.ChangeTab (System.Int32 tab) (at Assets/Scripts/Controller.cs:54)
Controller.AddTask () (at Assets/Scripts/Controller.cs:63)
```

I have been trying nonstop for days to figure out what is causing it, but i have found nothgin
Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Controller : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Store All
    List<string> taskNames = new List<string>();
    List<string> taskDesc = new List<string>();
    List<int> taskPriorities = new List<int>();
    List<int> taskTab = new List<int>();
    //Active Tab
    List<string> actTaskNames = new List<string>();
    List<string> actTaskDesc = new List<string>();
    List<int> actTaskPriority = new List<int>();
    //Input Fields
    [SerializeField] InputField taskName;
    [SerializeField] InputField taskPriority;
    [SerializeField] InputField taskDescription;
    //Task Displays
    [SerializeField] Text[] taskDisplays = new Text[5];
    //Task Input Field
    [SerializeField] GameObject TaskCreationMenu;
    //Page Display
    [SerializeField] Text pagesDisplay;
    //Other Variables
    int activeTab;
    int activePage;
    private void Start()
    {
        activeTab = 1;
        activePage = 1;
        ChangeTab(1);
    }
    public void ChangeTab(int tab)
    {
        activeTab = tab;

        actTaskNames.Clear();
        actTaskDesc.Clear();
        actTaskPriority.Clear();
        if(taskTab.Count >= 1)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < taskNames.Count; x++)
            {
                if (taskTab[x] == tab)
                {
                    actTaskNames.Add(taskNames[x]);
                    actTaskPriority.Add(taskPriorities[x]);
                    actTaskDesc.Add(taskDesc[x]);
                }
            }
            UpdateDisplays();
        }
    }
    public void AddTask()
    {
        taskNames.Add(taskName.text);
        taskDesc.Add(taskDescription.text);
        taskPriorities.Add(int.Parse(taskPriority.text));
        taskTab.Add(activeTab);
        ChangeTab(activeTab);
        TaskCreationMenu.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(1120f, -168f, 0f);
    }
    private void UpdatePages(int page)
    {
        if (taskNames.Count > 1)
        {
            int count = actTaskNames.Count;
            int countMod = count % 5;
            count -= countMod;
            int pages = 0;
            if (countMod != 0)
            {
                pages = 1;
            }
            pages += count / 5;
            activePage = page;
            pagesDisplay.text = ("page " + activePage + " of " + pages);
        }
    }
    private void UpdateDisplays()
    {
        int t = 0;
        for(int x = (0 + (activePage - 1 * 5)); x < (5 + (activePage - 1 * 5)); x++)
        {
            Debug.Log(t);
            if (actTaskNames.Count > x)
            {
                taskDisplays[t].text = (actTaskNames[x] + "\n" + actTaskDesc[x] + "\n" + actTaskPriority[x]);
            }
            else
            {
                taskDisplays[t].text = " ";
            }
            t++;
        }
        UpdatePages(activePage);
    }

    public void OpenTaskCreationMenu()
    {
        TaskCreationMenu.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 650, 0);
    }
}
```

And here is a screenshot of my Inspector configuration:

[image]

**I found  the answer**
The line

```
for(int x = (0 + (activePage - 1 * 5)); x < (5 + (activePage - 1 * 5)); x++)
```

is supposed to be

```
for(int x = (0 + ((activePage - 1) * 5)); x < (5 + ((activePage - 1) * 5)); x++)
```

Comment: So you stepped into this code with the debugger to see which index was out of range, `t` or `x` right? What's its value at that point, versus what is the size of the collection it's indexing into at that moment? etc. You have your full app available to step through and inspect, but we don't, so we're going to have to rely on you to provide this information to inform potential answers.

Comment: From what we can see, `activePage` is initialized to 1. It's only ever set to the argument `page` to which you pass the value of `activePage` itself. So it looks like it will always have a value of 1. `x = (0 + (activePage - 1 * 5))` is then `x = 0 + 1 - 5` or `x = -4` which is not a valid index into a list. Did you misplace a parenthesis in the calculation of `x`, or am I missing something in your code?

Comment: @DMGregory It is supposed to be this: x = (0 + ((activePage - 1) * 5)

Comment: You may find comments aren't a great way to share code. You can edit your question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I found  the answer**

The line

```
for(int x = (0 + (activePage - 1 * 5)); x < (5 + (activePage - 1 * 5)); x++)
```

is supposed to be

```
for(int x = (0 + ((activePage - 1) * 5)); x < (5 + ((activePage - 1) * 5)); x++)
```

Comment: You might want to make this answer the accepted one so that future visitors know it's good :)